# Printing a html table that fit size according to user selected the paper size

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have a html table, and a print option given on a web page where user able to print on A4 by default. when user click print, I use the javascript print functions to print it and it works perfectly, the result is a table that fit to a Full size of A4 page, but now my user want when they change the paper size in the properties, from A4 to A3, the same table to become orientation Landscape and table ,row,columns size to be adjusted where it will fit to the entire page of an A3 sheet

Comment: I see no question. Edit your post, please

Answer (score 2):

Use PDF. It was designed specifically for this purpose.

Javascipt and CSS do not allow you to control page orientation and page margins therefore you can never guarantee what will be printed in the end. You can create a solution for specific browser version and tell users to remove margins etc. but it is hardly a universal solution, and even then you still depend on printer's driver quirks.

Comment: DOM and CSS's lack of text positioning precision & control is becoming a big bottleneck for many needs. Interactive charts and diagrams that don't randomly truncate text, for example (with INPUTs etc). We need a new standard that fits common office/GUI/CRUD use. Social networks are stealing the attention, but office work is still here. Rise up! Shout it out! We need a better/new standard! DOM/CSS is the wrong tool for the office job!

Answer (score 0):

Just format tables using percent width instead of pixels. Also, if you want to set different style (i.e. white background) for printing just use `<style type="text/css" media="print">...</style>`